# Download document using Pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I am trying to download a document using Pyrogram via **file_id** and this program end with an error:

`pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.FileReferenceExpired: [400 FILE_REFERENCE_EXPIRED]: The file id contains an expired file reference, you must obtain a valid one by fetching the message from the origin context (caused by "upload.GetFile")`.

Code:

```py
import aiogram.utils.markdown as md
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot = Bot(token=BotToken)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

@dp.message_handler(content_types='document')
async def DownalodDocument(message: types.Message):
    await DownloadFile(message.document.file_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```

```
from pyrogram import Client

async def DownloadFile(file_id):
    async with Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash) as app:
        await app.download_media(file_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

`FileReferenceExpired` means the reference to the original file (`file_id`) is not valid now and has been expired. You need to fetch the `file_id` again after getting the message.

As a best practice, while using `file_id`, you should always handle the following errors:

```
FileReferenceEmpty
FileReferenceInvalid
FileReferenceExpired
FileIdInvalid
```

Catch them and fetch the `file_id` again on exception.